# Change color in tree view odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

Is it possible change color in tree view, for example if field total_time (float time widget) <= 00:00 put red color.

I'm try below exampke but not working!

```
colors="red:total_time<='00:00'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using following method.

```
colors="red:total_time&lt;='00:00'"
```

You must escaped special characters in XML.

Ex:

```
less than (<) is escaped to &lt;

greater than (>) is escaped to &gt;
```

This may help you.